# How to make white space to be counted as character in React Js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, whitespace

I have an array with strings which have white space, like this:

```
let myArr=["Hello       ", "Bonjour      ", "Buenos dias      "]
```

When I'm checking the length of each string, characters count includes white space too, but when I'm using these strings in a code, they don't have white space, for ex.when I'm mapping through array to display strings like this

```
myArr.map((h) => h)
```

in console.log strings length includes white space, but when I'm trying to display them in a code, they are shown without white space, so instead of **Hello                // should be a lot of space  ** it gets displayed as **Hello**with no space.

How can I make whitespace have the same length and width as characters? I need to display each strings the same length as in array ( having the same space after).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to render it inside html.
Try to use the pre tag or the css property
white-space: pre-wrap;

```
return (
    <div>
      <pre>{myArr.map((h) => h)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: then it's text is going outside it's div

Comment: Working fine for me


    let elements=["Hello       ", "Bonjour      ", "Buenosdias      
   "]
    return <div>

    <pre>{elements.map((h) => h)}</pre>


      </ div>

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code that can display the space in the html.

```
class TestArray extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let myArr=["Hello    1", "Bonjour  2", "Buenos dias      3"];
    return (<div>{myArr.map(h =><h1><pre>{h.length}{`${h}How are you?`}</pre></h1>)}
    </div>)
  }
}
  
ReactDOM.render(
  <TestArray />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: if I do myArr.map((h) => {return (<h2>{h} How are you? </h2>} )  h will be displayed as HelloHow are you, instead of Hello    (the same amount of space as in string) How are you. I need to display string with the same length as in string